# Cambio de dirección de los copos de nieve Python

Tags: python

Quiero hacer que los copos de nieve vallan de abajo hacia arriba, tengo un array donde voy almacenando los copos para luego ir imprimiéndolos en pantalla, y si un copo se escapa de la pantalla se posiciona arriba para volver a bajar
Pero ahora quiero hacerlo al revés que en lugar de que caigan, suban y se vallan poniendo abajo para poder seguir subiendo

````
import random
 
# Inicializamos el motor de juegos.
pygame.init()

NEGRO = [0, 0, 0]
BLANCO = [random.randrange(0, 255), random.randrange(0, 255), random.randrange(0, 255)]
 
# Establecemos el largo y ancho de la pantalla.
dimensiones = [800, 800]
 
pantalla = pygame.display.set_mode(dimensiones)
pygame.display.set_caption("Ya estoy harto")
 
# Creamos un array vacío
lista_nieve = []
 
# Iteramos 200 veces y añadimos un copo de nieve en una ubicación (x,y) aleatoria.
for i in range(200):
    x = random.randrange(0, 800)
    y = random.randrange(0, 800)
    lista_nieve.append([x, y])

 
reloj = pygame.time.Clock()
 
# Iteramos hasta que el usuario haga click sobre le botón de salida.
hecho = False
while not hecho:
     
    for evento in pygame.event.get():  # El usuario realizó alguna acción.
        if evento.type == pygame.QUIT: # Si el usuario hizo click sobre salir.
            hecho = True # Marcamos que hemos acabado y abandonamos este bucle.
 
    # Establecemos el color de fondo.
    pantalla.fill(NEGRO)
 
    # Procesamos cada copo de la lista.
    for i in range(len(lista_nieve)):
    
        # Dibujamos el copo de nieve
        pygame.draw.circle(pantalla, BLANCO, lista_nieve[i], 3)
        # Desplazamos un píxel hacia abajo el copo de nieve.
        lista_nieve[i][1] += -1      
        # Si el copo se escapa del fondo de la pantalla.
        if lista_nieve[i][1] > 800:
            # Lo movemos justo encima del todo
            y = random.randrange(-50, -10)
            lista_nieve[i][1] = y
            # Le damos una nueva ubicación x
            x = random.randrange(0, 800)
            lista_nieve[i][0] = x
             
    Avanzamos y actualizamos con lo que hemos dibujado.
    pygame.display.flip()
    
    reloj.tick(90)
             
pygame.quit () ```
````

Comment: Ibas bien! Solo tienes que cambiar esta comparación `lista_nieve[i][1] > 800` a `lista_nieve[i][1] < 0`. Es decir, si la coordenada de la bola de nieve es menor a 0 (la parte superior de la ventana). Lo unico que te diría es que la bola de nieve desaparecería antes de dejarse de ver, ya que el centro pasaría el y=0, mas no la parte inferior de la bola de nieve.

Comment: Añado, ya que hice una prueba. También tendrías que cambiar esta linea `y = random.randrange(-50, -10)` para que la coordenada nueva de y esté por arriba del 800 (la parte inferior de la ventana). Algo como `y = random.randrange(810, 850)`.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió de mucho, como le doy like a tu respuesta jajajaja

Comment: Me alegro de que te sirva c: Como lo resolvimos en los comentarios, no hay manera de que un like nos beneficie, pero si quieres puedes darle un +1 a mis comentarios :D

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque fue resuelta en los comentarios.